# Simulate HDMI monitor Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi, display-resolution

I'm running a video rendering server with Ubuntu 20.04 (records screen using ffmpeg and Xvfb)

I noticed that the "flow"/quality in the videos is much better when connecting a monitor and set the recording to display :0 instead of a virtual one. The monitor is 1080p and I want to record 4K without having to buy a HDMI dummy plug or a 4K monitor for that matter.

Can I somehow fake a HDMI or DisplayPort connected monitor so that my GPU (Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 Super) can handle the graphics?
Ideally the fake monitor would be a second monitor.

xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```